# If only using the first element, do I have to allocate mem for the whole struct?

Tags: c, struct

I have a structure where the first element is tested and dependent on its value the rest of the structure will or will not be read. In the cases where the first element's value dictates that the rest of the structure will not be read, do I have to allocate enough memory for the entire structure or just the first element?

```
struct element
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

int foo(struct element* e)
{
    if(e->x > 3)
        return e->y;
    return e->x;
}
```

in main:

```
int i = 0;
int z = foo((struct element*)&i);
```

I assume that if only allocating for the first element is valid, then I will have to be wary of anything that may attempt to copy the structure. i.e. passing the struct to a function.

Comment: Use code to explain the problem.

Comment: do not do this. coercing i into a struct is asking for maintenance trouble. It might work now but if somebody changes element then you are toast and it will be tough to track down. Even if this is a small project get into the habit of writing safe, maintainable code

Comment: Except for the *struct hack* or its modern incantation (the *flexible array member*) you cannot allocate part of a structure. You allocate space for a whole structure and use as many of its fields as you need.

Comment: Note that with C99 you could use a compound literal and write `int z = foo(&(struct element){ i });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't force your information into structs where it's not needed: don't use the struct as the parameter of your function.

either pass the member of your struct to the function or use inheritance:

```
typedef struct {
    int foo;
} BaseA;

typedef struct {
    int bar;
} BaseB;

typedef struct {
    BaseA a;
    BaseB b;
} Derived;

void foo(BaseB* info) { ... }

...
Derived d;
foo(&d.b);
BaseB b;
foo(&b);
```

if you're just curious (and seriously don't use this): you may.

```
typedef struct {
    int foo, goo, hoo, joo;
} A;

typedef struct {
    int unused, goo;
} B;

int foo(A* a) { return a->goo; }

...
B b;
int goo = foo((A*)&b);
```

In general you'll have to allocate a block of memory at least as many bytes as are required to fully read the accessed member with the largest offset in your structure. In addition when writing to this block you have to make sure to use the same member offsets as in the original structure.

The point being, a structure is only a block of memory with different areas assigned different interpretations (int, char, other structs etc...) and accessing a member of a struct (after reordering and alignment) boils down to simply reading from or writing to a bit of memory.

Comment: Huh? isn't that overkill?

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @Max not for two ints in this case let `foo` accept int and pass `bar` to it - but I assume OP has a more involved problem

Comment: @jayjay My stand is this: don't force yourself into using a structure when clearly (out of the data flow you describe) you don't need the whole structure at that point. I wanted to show you some possible code restructuring to avoid your problem in the first place.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios thanks for the edit, that clears things up. I don't know why on this site everyone assumes your doing something serious! :)

Comment: The "if you're just curious" part is wrong; `B` may have different layout to `A`, and depending on what `foo` does, there may be strict aliasing violation.or accessing out of bounds of `b`

Comment: @MattMcNabb not concerned about accessing outside the bounds, but you may be onto something with the strict aliasing. I have just been reading up on it and it seems like the bit of understanding I am missing. If you put that stuff in an answer I will change the accepted answer. Thanks

Comment: @jayjay in the code in your question there is no aliasing violation (it would only come if the code used the struct as a whole, e.g. `struct element f = *e;` when `e` does not actually point to a `struct element`).

Comment: I'm not sure whether your code is valid or not (it could have an alignment error, but we could check that before calling the function), that's why I haven't posted an answer

Comment: @MattMcNabb the point about the memory layout should be covered in the general case below, but you're right: aliasing can be a problem.

Comment: @MattMcNabb actually I ment *alignment issues*. I don't see any aliasing problems in my code.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think the code as given is legitimate.  To understand why, consider:

```
struct CHAR_AND_INT { unsigned char c; int i; }
CHAR_AND_INT *p;
```

A compiler would be entitled to assume that `p->c` will be word-aligned and have whatever padding would be necessary for `p->i` to also be word-aligned.  On some processors, writing a byte may be slower than writing a word.  For example, a byte-store instruction may require the processor to read a word from memory, update one byte within it, and write the whole thing back, while a word-store instruction could simply store the new data without having to read anything first.  A compiler that knew that `p->c` would be word-aligned and padded could implement `p->c = 12;` by using a word store to write the value 12.  Such behavior wouldn't yield desired results, however, if the byte following `p->c` wasn't padding but instead held useful data.

While I would not expect a compiler to impose "special" alignment or padding requirements on any part of the structure shown in the original question (beyond those which apply to `int`) I don't think anything in the standard would forbid a compiler from doing so.

Answer (score 0):

You need to only check that the structure itself is allocated; not the members (in that case at least)

```
int foo(struct element* e)
{
   if ( e != 0) // check that the e pointer is valid
   {
      if(e->x != 0) // here you only check to see if x is different than zero (values, not pointers)
        return e->y;
   }
    return 0;
}
```

In you edited change, I think this is poor coding

int i = 0;
int z = foo((struct element*)&i);

In that case, i will be allocation on the stack, so its address is valid; and will be valid in foo; but since you cast it into something different, the members will be garbage (at best)
Why do you want to cast an int into a structure? 
What is your intent?

Comment: maybe `e->x != 0` was a poor choice on my part to illustrate the problem, will update the question to say `e->x > 3`, thanks for the answer though.

Comment: As a note, an object defined as `int` may be incorrectly aligned for the structure (if it contains a member with stricter alignment requirements than `int`), in which case the `(struct element *)` conversion is undefined.

Comment: @mafso I don't think this is the case if the member in question is the first member in the struct. from the c std: "A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member ... and vice versa. There may be unnamed padding within as structure object, but not at its beginning."

Comment: @jayjay: The conversion itself is undefined in this case (C11 6.3.2.3 p7), so the pointer isn't "suitably converted".

Comment: @mafso Actually I'm not sure I do see... :S New question for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418753/structure-members-and-pointer-alignment