# structure members and pointer alignment

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Is a pointer to the struct aligned as if it were a pointer to the first element?

or

Is a conversion between a pointer to a struct and a pointer to the type of its first member (or visa versa) ever UB?

(I hope they are the same question...)

```
struct element
{
    tdefa x;
    tdefb y;
}; 

int foo(struct element* e);
int bar(tdefa* a);
```

~~~~~

```
tdefa i = 0;
foo((struct element*)&i);
```

or

```
struct element e;
bar((tdefa*)&e);
```

Where `tdefa` and `tdefb` could be defined as any type

Background:

I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28413882/if-only-using-the-first-element-do-i-have-to-allocate-mem-for-the-whole-struct)
and a user in a comment on one of the answers brought up C11 6.3.2.3 p7 that states:

> "A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a
>   different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly
>   aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined"

However I am having trouble working out when this would become an issue, my understanding was that padding would allow all members of the struct to be aligned correctly. Have I misunderstood?

and if:

```
struct element e;
tdefa* a = &e.x;
```

would work then:

```
tdefa* a = (tdefa*)&e;
```

would too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is never any initial padding; the first member of a struct is required to start at the same address as the struct itself.

You can always access the first member of a struct by casting a pointer to the whole struct, to be a pointer to the type of the first member.

Your `foo` example might run into trouble because `foo` will be expecting its argument to point to a `struct element` which in fact it does not, and there might be an alignment mismatch.

However the `bar` example and the final example is fine.

Comment: even if `foo1` only used the first element of the struct? If so an you elaborate on the "trouble", thanks!

Comment: @jayjay that question appears [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28413882/if-only-using-the-first-element-do-i-have-to-allocate-mem-for-the-whole-struct)

Comment: Thats also my question... also the cause of my confusion on the matter apparently...

Comment: @ Matt McNabb Can you give an example of what `tdefa` and `tdefb` would have to be  in order for the foo call to fail?

Comment: @jayjay that question belongs on the other thread . don't start 2 questions asking exactly the same question

Comment: @jayjay your two Questions are different, I mean the question you just asked in this comment is a question about your other Question !   This Question is asking several different things too.

Comment: The call to `foo` could have an alignment error regardless of what the types are, and even if there is no alignment error, once we get inside `foo` then (see other question for discussion)

Comment: Do you, by any chance have a recommendation of where I could go to learn more about alignment errors? I am having trouble visualising a case where an instance of a structure would be aligned differently to an instance of the type the structures first element. Thanks, you have been very helpful.

Comment: @jayjay `struct S { char c; int d; }`  : the whole struct probably will have the same alignment as `int`, and there would probably be padding between `c` and `d`.  If you write `char ch;` then  `(S *)&c` may trigger an alignment error because `ch` may not have happened to be aligned correctly for `int`. in this case.

Comment: Really, thats interesting, thanks again. It all makes sense now :)

Comment: @jayjay there doesn't seem to be a generic "What is alignment?" question on SO; there is a little bit of info in [this C FAQ entry](http://c-faq.com/struct/padding.html)

Answer (score 2):

A pointer to a structure always points to its initial member.

Here is the citation directly from [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (6.7.2.1, paragraph 13), emphasis mine:

> Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units in which bit-fields reside have addresses that increase in the order in which they are declared. **A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member** (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides)**, and vice versa. There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning**

#### As for your `foo` and `bar` examples:

The call to `bar` will be fine, as `bar` expects a `tdefa`, which is exactly what it's getting.

The call to `foo`, however, is problematic. `foo` expects a full `struct element`, but you're only passing a `tdefa` (while the struct consists of both `tdefa` *and* `tdefb`).